# Turn off "error" about missing no-arg constructor in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, openjpa

I'm using open-jpa and as we know it's shipped with enhancer which could create non private no-arg constructor during enhancement. It works, however eclipse have problem with it. It's quite rational that it doesn't know anything what would happen during ant build, so is there any possibility to turn off this particular error `The Java class for mapped type ... must define a non-private zero-argument constructor` bounded to @Entity annotation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me (Eclipse Mars.1 Release 4.5.1)

```
Project / Properties / JPA / Errors/Warnings
Enable Project Specific Settings
 Type
  ID class must have a public no-arg constructor (change from Error to something else)
```

Comment: Old question. This weren't in previous versions I guess but since it's from Mars upwards I accept answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply create a `non-private zero-arg constructor`

for example:

```
public foo(){
   super();
}
```

Comment: While this will get rid of the error, it adds unneeded code to the classes. It would be simpler long term to disable the warning in Eclipse.

Comment: I think if you want to keep the warning active for projects overall, and just resolve a particular instance of error, it is easier to add the dummy codes.

Comment: It depends really. If it means adding otherwise un-needed code to all of your entities, then the warning is probably not accurate? Another option would be to explicitly supress the warning at the site.